# how to avoid [Content_Types].xml in .net's ZipPackage class

Tags: .net, .net-4.0, zip

I wish to know if there is any way to avoid to have a **[Content_Types].xml** file inside the zip file while using .net's ***ZipPackage*** class.

Comment: whats your reason for using `ZipPackage`? If you wish to create a zip file out of existing documents, you are better off using `GZipStream` & related classes in the `System.IO.Compression` namespace.

Comment: @shahkalpesh: GZipStream is for single files only.

Comment: @Henk: I wish to create a ".zip" file for a single document. Is it possible to create ".zip" file using GZipStream ?

Comment: @Kushal: No, not if you want to read it with other Zip tools.

Comment: .NET 4.5 added a ZipArchive class to do this (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.compression.ziparchive%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

No.

Zip Packages are not (normal) Zip files. They must follow an imposed structure and contain that `Content_Types.xml` file in the root.   `ZipPackage = ZipArchive + Structure`.

If you want to create (and especially if you want to read) normal Zip archives you will need an extra library, there is no support in the BCL.

See [SharpZipLib](http://www.icsharpcode.net/opensource/sharpziplib/) (GPL) and [DotNetZip](http://dotnetzip.codeplex.com/)

Comment: What do you mean by "normal" ? Is it not possible to create a ".zip" file using whatever is there inside .net framework ?

Comment: @Kushal: Package = Zip Archive + Structure. So you can read a Zip Package with WinZip, but you cannot read (all) Zip files with ZipPackage

Comment: I just wish to zip a single file. But I am not able to get rid of .xml file which gets embedded with the package.

Comment: The contents.xml is what makes it a package.

Answer (score 5):

If you don't call the .Flush() method, there will be no such file

Comment: This is an excellent answer to this question, and this technique worked for me. If you create your `ZipPackage` with a memory stream, add your parts, and then copy the stream before disposing the `ZipPackage` (which calls `.Flush()`) then the resulting zip file contains only your added parts and no "[Context_Types].xml".

Comment: @DLeh Sorry what do you mean? This is exactly the method, to avoid the file been added to the zip file.

Comment: @MattKlein Thanks. I found this by accident (I forgot to dispose). But it seems to be working.

Comment: Flushes who? Package, MemoryStream etc?

Comment: @MattKlein what if I need to add multiple files? I have to flush it before opening it for next file.

Answer (score 2):

**Yes you can create zip packages without the extra XML content file added**

Inspired by this link: [Using System.IO.Packaging to generate a ZIP file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6386113/using-system-io-packaging-to-generate-a-zip-file)

Using above discovery mentioned by [Yiping](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3559256/yiping) you can avoid the extra xml file added into the package. Save zip stream from memory stream to a physical zip file before zip archive is closed like this:

```
public static void AddFilesToZip(string zipFilename, List<String> filesToAdd)
{
    using (var memStream = new MemoryStream())
    {
        using (Package zip = System.IO.Packaging.Package.Open(memStream, FileMode.Create))
        {

            foreach (var fileToAdd in filesToAdd)
            {
                string destFilename = ".\\" + Path.GetFileName(fileToAdd);
                Uri uri = PackUriHelper.CreatePartUri(new Uri(destFilename, UriKind.Relative));

                //Existing parts not likely in fresh memory stream
                if (zip.PartExists(uri))
                {
                    zip.DeletePart(uri);
                }

                PackagePart part = zip.CreatePart(uri, "", CompressionOption.Normal);

                using (FileStream fileStream = new FileStream(fileToAdd, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
                {

                    using (Stream dest = part.GetStream())
                    {
                        CopyStream(fileStream, dest);
                    }
                }
            }

            //The zip Package will add an XML content type file to memeory stream when it closes
            //so before it closes we save the memorystream to physical zip file.
            using (FileStream zipfilestream = new FileStream(zipFilename, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write))
            {
                memStream.Position = 0;
                CopyStream(memStream, zipfilestream);
            }

            // That's it. Zip file saved to file. Things added by package after this point will be to memory stream finally disposed.
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Got this working, thanks. The important part is memStream.Position = 0; without this you will get an empty zip.

Comment: Where `CopyStream` comes? I tested your code, but when I extract the content of the .zip, says that the .zip is damaged.

Comment: It works, but it will throw OutOfMemoryException on web environment if there's a lot of files.

Answer (score 1):

Man, this helped me a lot! You rock! I had to use this because my old framework (3.5). Only to complement, see below the implementation of the CopyStream function:

```
    private void CopyStream(Stream source, Stream target)
    {
        const int bufSize = 0x1000;
        byte[] buf = new byte[bufSize];
        int bytesRead = 0;
        while ((bytesRead = source.Read(buf, 0, bufSize)) > 0)
            target.Write(buf, 0, bytesRead);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also set private field `_contentTypeHelper` of `System.IO.Packaging.Package` to `null` ( using `DynamicObject` ).

Answer (score 0):

Run this function when you finish packing your zip file:

```
public static void Remove_Content_Types_FromZip(string zipFileName)
    {
        string contents;
        using (ZipFile zipFile = new ZipFile(File.Open(zipFileName, FileMode.Open)))
        {
            /*
            ZipEntry startPartEntry = zipFile.GetEntry("[Content_Types].xml");
            using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(zipFile.GetInputStream(startPartEntry)))
            {
                contents = reader.ReadToEnd();
            }
            XElement contentTypes = XElement.Parse(contents);
            XNamespace xs = contentTypes.GetDefaultNamespace();
            XElement newDefExt = new XElement(xs + "Default", new XAttribute("Extension", "sab"), new XAttribute("ContentType", @"application/binary; modeler=Acis; version=18.0.2application/binary; modeler=Acis; version=18.0.2"));
            contentTypes.Add(newDefExt);
            contentTypes.Save("[Content_Types].xml");
            zipFile.BeginUpdate();
            zipFile.Add("[Content_Types].xml");
            zipFile.CommitUpdate();
            File.Delete("[Content_Types].xml");
            */
            zipFile.BeginUpdate();
            try
            {
                zipFile.Delete("[Content_Types].xml");
                zipFile.CommitUpdate();
            }
            catch{}
        }
    }
```