# Using System.IO.Packaging to generate a ZIP file

Tags: c#, .net, zip

I know that the likes of the DotNetZip or SharpZipLib libraries are usually recommended for creating ZIP files in a .net language (C# in my case), but it's not *impossible* to use `System.IO.Packaging` to generate a ZIP file.  I thought it might be nice to try and develop a routine in C# which could do it, without the need to download any external libraries.  Does anyone have a good example of a method or methods that will use `System.IO.Packaging` to generate a ZIP file?

Comment: OK, after reading around a bit, it looks like the awkwardness of using System.IO.Packaging isn't the only reason people avoid it like the plague; it also generates a silly [Content_Types].xml file in every zip in generates, and there are serious question marks as to its compatibility with other zip file clients. So... I guess I'll be using DotNetZip. :-)

Answer (score 34, accepted):

let me google this for you -> system.io.packaging+generate+zip

first link
http://weblogs.asp.net/jongalloway//creating-zip-archives-in-net-without-an-external-library-like-sharpziplib

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.IO.Packaging;

namespace ZipSample
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            AddFileToZip("Output.zip", @"C:\Windows\Notepad.exe");
            AddFileToZip("Output.zip", @"C:\Windows\System32\Calc.exe");
        }

        private static void AddFileToZip(string zipFilename, string fileToAdd, CompressionOption compression = CompressionOption.Normal)
        {
            using (Package zip = System.IO.Packaging.Package.Open(zipFilename, FileMode.OpenOrCreate))
            {
                string destFilename = ".\\" + Path.GetFileName(fileToAdd);
                Uri uri = PackUriHelper.CreatePartUri(new Uri(destFilename, UriKind.Relative));
                if (zip.PartExists(uri))
                {
                    zip.DeletePart(uri);
                }
                PackagePart part = zip.CreatePart(uri, "", compression);
                using (FileStream fileStream = new FileStream(fileToAdd, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
                {
                    using (Stream dest = part.GetStream())
                    {
                        fileStream.CopyTo(dest);
                    }
                }
            }
        }              
    }
}
```

Comment: Sure, but this doesn't take a path, and add all its directories and files into the ZIP; one must specify the individual files manually.

Comment: Really you cannot implement it yourself ? :S

Comment: Look - Listing files in a directory in C# http://www.csharpfriends.com/Articles/getArticle.aspx?articleID=356

Comment: you dont, all the code is in my reply and my comment above, just use it and for each file from DirectoryInfo use AddFileToZip ... :P

Comment: OK, after reading around a bit, it looks like the awkwardness of using `System.IO.Packaging` isn't the only reason people avoid it like the plague; it also generates a silly `[Content_Types].xml` file in every zip in generates, and there are serious question marks as to its compatibility with other zip file clients.  So... I guess I'll be using DotNetZip.  :-)

Comment: Nice, thanks for this.Just want to mention that to use this code you must add a reference to WindowsBase dll to be able to use System.IO.Packaging

Comment: ironically, i googled exactly "create zip  System.IO.Packaging" and it showed this thread first.  you broke it.

Comment: me thinks that last line should read:
   bytesWritten += bytesRead;

Comment: @erict - or: both lines containing bytesWritten can be omitted

Comment: *"let me google this for you..."* Wow, could you be more condescending if you tried? The way this answer is phrased is only one or two steps above a [LMGTFY link, which Stack Overflow frowns upon](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/255397/lmgtfy-link-cant-be-added).

Comment: "Let me google this for you..." Seriously ? Please read this ! https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9953/could-we-please-be-a-bit-nicer-to-new-users You answer is correct, thanks, but your behavior is horrible -> downvote

Answer (score 11):

In .NET Framework 4.5 you can use the new classes in the [`System.IO.Compression`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms404280(v=vs.110).aspx) namespace.