# System.IO.Packaging

Tags: c#, system.io.packaging

I have my project set to .NET Framework 4.0. When I add `System.IO.Packaging`, it says that it doesn't exist. It also doesn't show up when I try to add it as a reference to the project.

How can I add `System.IO.Packaging` to my C# project?

Answer (score 174, accepted):

According to a user comment on [this MSDN page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.packaging.aspx), you have to add a reference to the WindowsBase .Net library.

Comment: You don't even need a user comment. If you look at the docs for any of the actual methods/objects/etc. in the namespace, they all say "Assembly: WindowBase.dll"

Comment: When I went to the link in the answer, I didn't see how I would know to add the WindowsBase.Net library. I added it and I now have access to system.io.packaging.  So thanks for that, but could you explain what I'm not seeing about knowing to access the system.io.packaging through the WindowsBase.Net library?

Comment: The page used to have user comments which mentioned WindowsBase. It looks like Microsoft removed comments from their docs.

Answer (score 82):

For a C# solution in Visual Studio 2010 with .NET 4.0:

1. In your project's Solution Explorer, right-click on **References** and select **Add References** from the context menu.
2. Select **Assemblies** in the left-hand pane, then click the **Browse** button next to the **File name** field near the botton of the pane.
3. Browse to .NET 4.0 reference assemblies and select **WindowsBase.dll**. For example, on my machine (Windows 7, 64-bit) the complete path is:

> C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference
>   Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.0\WindowsBase.dll

**Save the solution** (especially if you're compiling from the command-line with MSBuild) and you should now be able to add the *using System.IO.Packaging* directive to the top of your .cs file without an error appearing.

Comment: No need to browse to dll, it's already available under Assemblies > Framework.

Comment: @AltafPatel for me it didn't show up, I had to browse to it. Also make sure that your project is set to compile with the matching .NET version of the referenced file(in this case 4.0).

Answer (score 5):

`System.IO.Packaging` is a namespace, not a reference.  Most (all?) of the classes within the namespace, such as [ZipPackage](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.packaging.zippackage.aspx), are deployed in `WindowsBase.dll`.

Make sure you have a reference to `WindowsBase.dll` - if you do, you can just add: using `System.IO.Packaging;` to your .cs files, and you'll be fine.

Note that you can see this in the [documentation for any class on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.packaging.zippackage.aspx).  For example, in `ZipPackage`, it lists:

```
Namespace:  System.IO.Packaging
Assembly:  WindowsBase (in WindowsBase.dll)
```

Comment: +1 - I didn't notice that individual pages note the assembly to use. I would have expected it on the main namespace page, but since those don't always match up, it makes sense to look at the classes you might need.

Answer (score 5):

We can add WindowsBase.dll in Dot Net framework 3.5 as well. I am using XP machine and Path for WindowsBase.dll is

> C:\Program Files\Reference
>   Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v3.5\Profile\Client\WindowsBase.dll

Example for using `System.IO.packaging` is given here -

[Using System.IO.Packaging to generate a ZIP file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6386113/using-system-io-packaging-to-generate-a-zip-file)

Answer (score 3):

The `System.IO.Packaging` namespace is provided by `WindowsBase`. When you add a reference, add `WindowsBase` as the reference instead of trying to find `System.IO.Packaging`.

Answer (score 3):

You need to add a reference to the WindowsBase.dll. System.IO.Packaging is located in there.

See this article for more details:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.packaging.package.aspx

Answer (score 2):

System.IO.Packaging v4.0.30319 is in WindowsBase.dll v4.0.30319

For windows 10 maybe you could found here

C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\assembly\GAC_MSIL\WindowsBase\v4.0_4.0.0.0__31bf3856ad364e35\

Answer (score 0):

In my case I was using a ashx handler. For it to work you need to add the assembly to the project and the handler:

```
<%@ WebHandler Language="C#" Class="UploadExcelFile2" %>
<%@ Assembly Name="WindowsBase, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" %>
```

This finally worked for me, tried multiple times to add WindowsBase as reference(restarted VS, restarted machine too) but still it was not working till I added this explicitly in my aspx page. I used: `<%@ Assembly Name="WindowsBase, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" %>` as the dll i had referenced was version 4.0.