# Error publishing website with windowsBase.dll

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013

Using Visual Studio Express 2013 for Web

I am using System.IO.Packaging to edit a Word document using linq to xml.

After following instructions in this SO page [System.IO.Packaging](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7260339/system-io-packaging%5C) I added the reference to WindowsBase.dll.

All this works well and I get the desired results. When I try and publish to my web server though, during the compile I receive this error

*The type or namespace name 'Packaging' does not exist in the namespace 'System.IO' Are you missing an assembly reference?*

Thanks

Comment: when you stated to develop this ...did you select Web Application, or new Web Site..?

Comment: have you looked at this [MSDN  How to: Create a WebDeployment Package](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd465323(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: Its a website. I will try and convert it, and then see what options I have. Thanks

Comment: Converted to a web application, now all is good. Thanks

Comment: glad that was a quick simple fix. glad to help

Answer (score 0):

Mark the WindowsBase reference as `Copy Local` and it will be included in the package/deploy

Comment: you mean `CopyLocal=true` maybe you should explain that more perhaps the OP isn't aware that you `Click on the References-->Packaging.Dll` then in the properties window set the `CopyLocal=false, change that to true`

Comment: Thanks for your comments, but I cannot see the references in the solution explorer. If I open Project Properties, I can see the Windowsbase.dll reference, but I cannot open any properties. Could this be an Express limitation?

Comment: @pbs Right click on the reference and select properties, from there change "Copy Local" to true