# Creating in-memory archive with multiple files

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, pdf, sharpziplib

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Using System.IO.Packaging to generate a ZIP file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6386113/using-system-io-packaging-to-generate-a-zip-file)

I have a controller where i create multiple PDF files.

What i need to do is, foreach pdf i create in my controller, add it to a zip archive which is temporarily stored in memory(as i cannot use local resources), and then offer the zip archive as a download in my browser (asp page).

How can this be achieved?

Comment: Take a look to [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6386113/using-system-io-packaging-to-generate-a-zip-file) here on SO.