# "Bundle" a folder (e.g. Create an uncompressed zip) from PowerShell

Tags: powershell

I am doing a nightly backup of all files modified in the last day, using PowerShell.

The goal is to create an *uncompressed* zip (or any other format) that will group everything in the backup folder into one file, using PowerShell.

The following code works great for compression but it is far too slow:

```
function Add-Zip
{
    param([string]$zipfilename)

    if(-not (test-path($zipfilename)))
    {
        set-content $zipfilename ("PK" + [char]5 + [char]6 + ("$([char]0)" * 18)) 
        (dir $zipfilename).IsReadOnly = $false  
    }

    $shellApplication = new-object -com shell.application
    $zipPackage = $shellApplication.NameSpace($zipfilename)

    foreach($file in $input) 
    { 
        $zipPackage.CopyHere($file.FullName)
        Start-sleep -milliseconds 1000
        #500 milliseconds was too short.... 
    }
}
```

Any ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: You chose a hard way. Why don't you use any of available command line tools?

Comment: The powershell does more than what I showed above.  It was used to only get the files modified in the last day.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would recomend using powershell in conjunction with [7-Zip](http://7-zip.org/) Command line. 7-Zip has a [command line option](http://www.dotnetperls.com/7-zip-examples) that allows for No Compression.

```
-mx0
```

Comment: For anyone who's as lazy as I am, here's the full command `7z a -tzip archive.zip *.jpg -mx0`

Answer (score 4):

The [PowerShell Community Extensions](http://pscx.codeplex.com) has a `Write-Tar` cmdlet that might be of use here.

Answer (score 0):

Borrowing from [Eld's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13302548/2392683) to [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1153126/how-to-create-a-zip-archive-with-powershell), I came up with:

```
function ZipFiles( $zipfilename, $sourcedir )
{
   [Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("System.IO.Compression.FileSystem")
   $compressionLevel = [System.IO.Compression.CompressionLevel]::NoCompression
   [System.IO.Compression.ZipFile]::CreateFromDirectory($sourcedir,
        $zipfilename, $compressionLevel, $false)
}
```

Eld also says of his solution, which applies here as well:

> A pure Powershell alternative that works with Powershell 3 and .NET 4.5 (if you can use it):

The change from his answer was to specify `NoCompression` instead of `Optimal` for the level.