# How to compress multiple files into one zip with PowerShell?

Tags: powershell, zip, pipe

I want to compress multiple files into one zip.

I am stuck with this at the moment:

```
Get-ChildItem -path C:\logs -Recurse | Where {$_.Extension -eq ".csv" -and $_.LastWriteTime -lt (Get-Date).AddDays(-7)} | write-zip -level 9 -append ($_.LastWriteTime).zip | move-item -Force -Destination {
    $dir = "C:\backup\archive"
    $null = mkdir $dir -Force
    "$dir\"
}
```

I get this exception

> Write-Zip : Cannot bind argument to parameter 'Path' because it is null.

This part is the problem:

```
write-zip -level 9 -append ($_.LastWriteTime).zip
```

I have never used powershell before but i have to provide a script, I can't provide a c# solution.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The problem is that [Get-ChildItem](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd347686.aspx) returns instances of the [System.IO.FileInfo](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.fileinfo.aspx) class, which doesn't have a property named `Path`. Therefore the value cannot be automatically mapped to the `Path` parameter of the [Write-Zip](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1153126/how-to-create-a-zip-archive-with-powershell/1153144#1153144) cmdlet through piping.

You'll have to use the [ForEach-Object](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd347608.aspx) cmdlet to zip the files using the [System.IO.FileInfo.FullName](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filesysteminfo.fullname.aspx) property, which contains the full path:

```
Get-ChildItem -Path C:\Logs | Where-Object { $_.Extension -eq ".txt" } | ForEach-Object { Write-Zip -Path $_.FullName -OutputPath "$_.zip" }
```

Here's a shorter version of the command using [aliases](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee692685.aspx) and positional parameters:

```
dir C:\Logs | where { $_.Extension -eq ".txt" } | foreach { Write-Zip $_.FullName "$_.zip" }
```

**Related resources:**

- [Cool Pipeline Tricks, Redux (TechNet Magazine)](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/ff394367.aspx)

Comment: If you want to make it even shorter you can move the filter into the `Get-ChildItem` call like this: `dir c:\Logs *.txt | foreach { Write-Zip $_.FullName "$_.zip" }`