# System.IO.Packaging: Unable to determine the identity of the domain

Tags: .net, isolatedstorage, open-packaging-convention

I'm using System.IO.Packaging to create files in a completely managed desktop (Windows Forms) application.

Under certain conditions, the writing of the OPC package raises the *"Unable to determine the identity of the domain"* exception. I have learned that it is related to Isolated Storage, as the Packaging API sometimes creates temporary data there.

I haven't found a reliable reproduction of this, but I believe it occurs when data is over a certain size (a few megabytes compressed), and perhaps also depending on the type of user account running the application.

- What is "the domain"? My AppDomain? What controls its "identity" in a normal windows forms app?
- How can I avoid this problem (apart from manually creating the zip archive files without OPC)?

Comment: +1 how did you link the error message with isolated storage (url or ProcessMonitor or something). When you encounter the problem is it on certain dev PC's? what makes you think its a size issue, do smaller packages work?

Comment: http://rekiwi.blogspot.com.au/2008/12/unable-to-determine-identity-of-domain.html

Comment: The exception is an IsolatedStorageException. The link between OPC and  Isolated Storage is explained in various articles/blog posts, for example the one you linked to.