# Isolated Storage Exception: Unable to determine the identity of domain

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, sql-server-2012, reportserver

I setup a subscription in a SQL Server 2012 SP1 Reporting Services instance that exports a 34MB file to the Excel 2007-2013 XLSX OpenXML render extension.  The subscription throws the following error:

**System.IO.IsolatedStorage.IsolatedStorageException: Unable to determine the identity of domain.**

I verified it is possible to export the report from Report Manager to the Excel 2007-2013 XLSX OpenXML render extension without a problem.  This error only occurs when the report is executed via a subscription.  I have researched this and found the following recommendations on the web:

1. Two separate Microsoft Connect bug reports [764356](https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/764356/subscription-fails-due-to-error-system-io-isolatedstorage-isolatedstorageexception-unable-to-determine-the-identity-of-domain) and [764556](https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/764556/rrrendering-error-when-rendering-larger-reports-to-xlsx-via-subscription-sql-2012) that have no listed work arounds.
2. A recommendation to stagger the subscriptions so that only one runs at a time.  This does not help since only one subscription is running at the time of the error.
3. A recommendation to use the Excel 2003 render method and break the rows into separate tabs to avoid the 65,536 row limit.  I did verify this works, but this was not an acceptable solution from the business stakeholder's perspective.
4. A comment indicating any report using the Excel 2007-2013 render method that exceeds 10 MB in size switches from being generated in memory to using Isolated Storage.  There's no explanation why this is bad and I assume this was done for a good reason -- perhaps to limit RAM consumption.
5. A suggestion to elevate permissions for users in the Isolated Storage folder for the ASP.NET application.  I could not find where the Isolated Storage folder is located for Reporting Services.
6. A suggestion to wrap the ASP.NET's code for Isolated Storage with extra code that by-passes this problem.  I couldn't find a way to apply this solution to Reporting Services since this is a shipped product from Microsoft.
7. A suggestion to modify the Report Manager and Report Server web.config files to include maxRequestLength="200000" in the httpRuntime node.  This did not change the results.
8. A suggestion to increase memory settings explicitly in RSReportServer.config.  This didn't seem like it would help since the error relates to Isolated Storage, but I tried it out of desparation.  This did not change the results.
9. A suggestion to change the DatabaseQueryTimeout value from 120 to something larger.  This did not change the results.
10. A suggestion to change the Subscription execution timeout value.  This did not change the results.

Below is a copy of the full error log entry:

```
reportrendering!WindowsService_5!1628!04/03/2013-09:48:33:: e ERROR: Throwing Microsoft.ReportingServices.ReportProcessing.UnhandledReportRenderingException: , Microsoft.ReportingServices.ReportProcessing.UnhandledReportRenderingException: An error occurred during rendering of the report. ---> Microsoft.ReportingServices.OnDemandReportRendering.ReportRenderingException: An error occurred during rendering of the report. ---> System.IO.IsolatedStorage.IsolatedStorageException: Unable to determine the identity of domain.
   at System.IO.IsolatedStorage.IsolatedStorage._GetAccountingInfo(Evidence evidence, Type evidenceType, IsolatedStorageScope fAssmDomApp, Object& oNormalized)
   at System.IO.IsolatedStorage.IsolatedStorage.GetAccountingInfo(Evidence evidence, Type evidenceType, IsolatedStorageScope fAssmDomApp, String& typeName, String& instanceName)
   at System.IO.IsolatedStorage.IsolatedStorage._InitStore(IsolatedStorageScope scope, Evidence domainEv, Type domainEvidenceType, Evidence assemEv, Type assemblyEvidenceType, Evidence appEv, Type appEvidenceType)
   at System.IO.IsolatedStorage.IsolatedStorage.InitStore(IsolatedStorageScope scope, Type domainEvidenceType, Type assemblyEvidenceType)
   at System.IO.IsolatedStorage.IsolatedStorageFile.GetStore(IsolatedStorageScope scope, Type domainEvidenceType, Type assemblyEvidenceType)
   at MS.Internal.IO.Packaging.PackagingUtilities.ReliableIsolatedStorageFileFolder..ctor()
   at MS.Internal.IO.Packaging.PackagingUtilities.GetDefaultIsolatedStorageFile()
   at MS.Internal.IO.Packaging.PackagingUtilities.CreateUserScopedIsolatedStorageFileStreamWithRandomName(Int32 retryCount, String& fileName)
   at MS.Internal.IO.Packaging.SparseMemoryStream.EnsureIsolatedStoreStream()
   at MS.Internal.IO.Packaging.SparseMemoryStream.SwitchModeIfNecessary()
   at MS.Internal.IO.Zip.ZipIOFileItemStream.Write(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 count)
   at System.IO.Compression.DeflateStream.InternalWrite(Byte[] array, Int32 offset, Int32 count, Boolean isAsync)
   at System.IO.Compression.DeflateStream.Write(Byte[] array, Int32 offset, Int32 count)
   at MS.Internal.IO.Packaging.CompressStream.Write(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 count)
   at MS.Internal.IO.Zip.ProgressiveCrcCalculatingStream.Write(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 count)
   at MS.Internal.IO.Zip.ZipIOModeEnforcingStream.Write(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 count)
   at Microsoft.ReportingServices.Rendering.ExcelOpenXmlRenderer.XMLModel.XMLStreamsheetModel.WriteStreamToStream(Stream from, Stream to)
   at Microsoft.ReportingServices.Rendering.ExcelOpenXmlRenderer.XMLModel.XMLStreamsheetModel.Cleanup()
   at Microsoft.ReportingServices.Rendering.ExcelOpenXmlRenderer.OpenXmlGenerator.FinalizeWorksheet()
   at Microsoft.ReportingServices.Rendering.ExcelOpenXmlRenderer.OpenXmlGenerator.NextWorksheet()
   at Microsoft.ReportingServices.Rendering.ExcelRenderer.ExcelRenderer.Render(Report report, NameValueCollection reportServerParameters, NameValueCollection deviceInfo, NameValueCollection
```

Comment: Unfortunately it appears you have found a bug or limitation in the reporting services Excel renderer (although if you can generate the report through Report Manager then it sounds like a bug to me). 34 MB is a fairly large spreadsheet report. Is this actually a report or is it a data extract? Can it be exported as CSV instead of Excel format? Could you use SSIS to export the data to a spreadsheet instead?

Comment: I updated the Connect bugs to include information from this question.  I worked around this bug by rending the report via the ReportServer URL in a SSIS package script task.

Answer (score 6):

You can find a solution here: http://rekiwi.blogspot.com/2008/12/unable-to-determine-identity-of-domain.html

In the COM component, create a new AppDomain with the appropriate evidence and execute the code in that.

Here is a code example that fixed the problem for me:

```
AppDomainSetup setup = new AppDomainSetup();
setup.ApplicationBase = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory.ToString();

//Then we need our evidence
System.Security.Policy.Evidence evidence = new System.Security.Policy.Evidence();
evidence.AddHost(new System.Security.Policy.Zone(System.Security.SecurityZone.MyComputer));

//Now we can fire up an AppDomain running with that evidence.
AppDomain domain = AppDomain.CreateDomain("YourDll.YourClass", evidence, setup);

YourDll.YourClass yourclass = (YourDll.YourClass)domain.CreateInstanceAndUnwrap(typeof(YourDll.YourClass).Assembly.FullName, typeof(YourDll.YourClass).FullName);

yourclass.CallYourMethod();
```

Any types you want to marshall across AppDomains have to marked [Serializable()] and must inherit from MarshalByRefObject.
For example:

```
namespace YourDll
{
[Serializable()]
public class YourClass: MarshalByRefObject
{
...
```