# SSRS Subscription Failure - An error occurred during rendering of the report

Tags: sql-server, excel, reporting-services, subscriptions

I have created a subscription that will place a report on a file share. When the subscription runs to build an excel file and put it on the shared drive, it gives the following error:

```
 Failure writing file [Report Name] : An error occurred during rendering of the report.
```

When I looked in the logs I saw a little bit more detail, but it didnt mean much to me, as I am new to SSRS development.

Here is what i am getting:

```
 An error occurred during rendering of the report. ---> 
 Microsoft.ReportingServices.ReportProcessing.UnhandledReportRenderingException: 
 An error occurred during rendering of the report. ---> 
  Microsoft.ReportingServices.OnDemandReportRendering.ReportRenderingException: An 
 error occurred during rendering of the report. ---> 
 System.IO.IsolatedStorage.IsolatedStorageException: Unable to determine the
  identity of domain.
```

What doesnt make sense to me is that I changed the file type on the export to CSV and it will export.  What is even more shocking is that the CSV file is bigger than the excel file (i was able to do a manual export through the UI for the report.)

Any ideas on what is going on and how I can resolve this?

Thanks,

Craig

Comment: For part of your question, there is a compression algorithm uesd on .xslx files.  That's probably why it's smaller than the CSV.

Comment: The error message sounds like some kind of network trust issue.   Do you have any network engineers you can bring in on it?

Comment: There's a link between this error and the size of the file, where the manual export from Report Manager works, but the subscription fails.  do you have a file bigger than 10MB or more than 64k rows on any of the tabs?  If so, check out this SO question:  [Isolated Storage Exception...](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15795458/isolated-storage-exception-unable-to-determine-the-identity-of-domain)

Comment: I have exactly the same problem. I STRONGLY believe the excel file is too large to render for SSRS.  I do export to csv instead.

Comment: Greenspark - The file was over 10MB.  One of them was over 30MB.  Looks like it has to do with the excel renderer according to the link you provided.  I'll have to test out the direct link that was mentioned in the article.