# SSRS Subscription error "An error occurred during rendering of the report"

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008

When i subscribe report with xls format it complete successfully but when i subscribe report with xlsx then above error occur. i am not understanding problem help me..

i am using sql server 2008 R2.

```
An error occurred during rendering of the report. ---> 
 Microsoft.ReportingServices.ReportProcessing.UnhandledReportRenderingException: 
 An error occurred during rendering of the report. ---> 
  Microsoft.ReportingServices.OnDemandReportRendering.ReportRenderingException: An 
 error occurred during rendering of the report. ---> 
 System.IO.IsolatedStorage.IsolatedStorageException: Unable to determine the
  identity of domain.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This looks like a Microsoft bug, see here https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/764556/rrrendering-error-when-rendering-larger-reports-to-xlsx-via-subscription-sql-2012

Plus this has been asked here on SO before along with some suggestions on what to do about it - [Isolated Storage Exception: Unable to determine the identity of domain](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15795458/isolated-storage-exception-unable-to-determine-the-identity-of-domain)