# PowerShell: move files to zip with System.IO.Compression.FileSystem

Tags: .net, logging, powershell, compression, zip

How can I *move log* files to zip archives with System.IO.Compression.FileSystem in PowerShell?

I have more folders with log files per application:

```
app1logfolder
|-app1_20130507.log
|-app1_20130508.log
|-app1_20130509.log

app2logfolder
|-app2_20130507.log
|-app2_20130508.log
|-app2_20130509.log
```

and so on.. And I want to process these files into a zip archive per day.

```
logs_20130507.zip
|-app1_20130507.log
|-app2_20130507.log

logs_20130508.zip
|-app1_20130508.log
|-app2_20130508.log

logs_20130509.zip
|-app1_20130509.log
|-app2_20130509.log
```

Answer (score 3):

You could build a script around something like this, which will take a folder and put its content into a compressed zip file.

```
$srcdir = "C:\folderYouWantZipped"
$zipFilename = "nameZipfile.zip"
$zipFilepath = "C:\ZipfileLoaction\"
$zipFile = "$zipFilepath$zipFilename"

#Prepare zip file
if(-not (test-path($zipFile))) {
    set-content $zipFile ("PK" + [char]5 + [char]6 + ("$([char]0)" * 18))
    (dir $zipFile).IsReadOnly = $false  
}

$shellApplication = new-object -com shell.application
$zipPackage = $shellApplication.NameSpace($zipFile)
$files = Get-ChildItem -Path $srcdir | where{! $_.PSIsContainer}

foreach($file in $files) { 
    $zipPackage.CopyHere($file.FullName)
#using this method, sometimes files can be 'skipped'
#this 'while' loop checks each file is added before moving to the next
    while($zipPackage.Items().Item($file.name) -eq $null){
        Start-sleep -seconds 1
    }
}
```

**More Links that mite help:**

- https://serverfault.com/questions/456095/zipping-only-files-using-powershell
- [How to create a zip archive with PowerShell?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1153126/how-to-create-a-zip-archive-with-powershell)
- http://www.technologytoolbox.com/blog/jjameson/archive/2012/02/28/zip-a-folder-using-powershell.aspx

Answer (score 0):

You can do using below code. Simply paste below code in `.ps1` file and call `ZipFiles` function like `ZipFiles $sourceFolderPath $zipFileName`

```
    function ZipFiles($sourcedir, $zipfilename)
    {
       if ($zipfilename -notMatch ".zip")
       {
            $zipfilename = $zipfilename + ".zip"
       }       
       $onelevelup=Split-Path -Path $sourcedir -Parent
       $zipfilename = $onelevelup + "\" + $zipFileName

       Add-Type -Assembly System.IO.Compression.FileSystem
       $compressionLevel = [System.IO.Compression.CompressionLevel]::Optimal
       [System.IO.Compression.ZipFile]::CreateFromDirectory($sourcedir, $zipfilename, $compressionLevel, $false)

       CopyFile $zipfilename $sourcedir
    }

    function CopyFile( $copySource, $destinationSource)
    {
      Copy-Item $copySource $destinationSource -Recurse
    }
```