# Add version file to msbuild package to deploy via web deploy without custom build script

Tags: version-control, msbuild, jenkins, continuous-integration

I have been trying to work with msbuild from the command line for CI reasons. I know that I could write an xml build script and work with msbuild that way but we obviously need our CI system to work the same way for all our CI jobs. We have 69 (dev,qa,trunk) jobs that we would have to rewrite and we don’t really have the time.

We currently run msbuild with the following targets and properties from the command line … like so.
/target:Rebuild;Package /p:DeployOnBuild=True;Configuration=Debug;_PackageTempDir=".\PackageTemp";PackageAsSingleFile=true;PackageLocation=".\obj\Debug\360Survey.zip"

This produces the zip file and also produces a file called 360Survey.deploy.cmd which as you know we use to deploy with web deploy from the command line.

The problem we are trying to solve is that we don’t currently have a way to know exactly what source revision is in production. So during this process we want to add to the zip file another file containing the source revision number and possibly some other build information so that we can always know what version of code was deployed to production.

Perhaps part of our problem stems from a process issue, but until we get that resolved we were hoping to make a small adjustment to our CI process that would pick up some of the slack.

I have made several different attempts at this with google searches but I haven’t been able to make it work.

1. I tried not packaging as a zip file, but then I didn’t get the deploy.cmd file.
2. I tried specifying a temporary out path using the following property. _PackageTempDir=".\PackageTemp" Adding the file to that folder and then calling the package target but that seemed to delete the temp folder and recreate it removing our version file.
3. I tried several different combinations of the different properties we’ve used

Obviously I have a lack of understanding of how exactly msbuild works and what targets depend on other targets and how I can customize each of them by overriding the default properties. I of course understand that it might not be possible to do what I want without writing a custom build script but I can’t find anyone on the net that has said otherwise. I have looked at the msdn documentation but it’s not clear on exactly what properties you can change and how they might affect the different targets when running msbuild from the command line. Most of the sites I’ve seen go into some detail about writing a custom build script but don’t really say all that much about the command line.

Comment: Since you have a zip file, can't you just add an extra build step that opens the zip and adds a text file with version info to it? Or even just adjust the zip file comment?

Comment: Btw a nice way to get version info into a build, at least for c++/c# dlls and exes is to have a pre-build step in which you fetch the version info, then use it to create a version resource (c++) or adjust the AssemblyInfo.cs (c#). Not sure how that applies to web as I have no experience with it at all.

Comment: @stijn How would I add that file to the zip from the command line? Is that possible? Ultimately we could modify the assemblyinfo file. Though I feel that having a text file or modifying properties of the assembly info file are pretty close. And once again I'm not sure how I would go about modifying the assemblyinfo file without a custom build script from the command line?

Answer (score 0):

There are lots of ways to add a file (or files) to an existing zip file: in an msbuild script using [MsBuildTasks](https://github.com/loresoft/msbuildtasks), in a [PowerShell script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1153126/how-to-create-a-zip-archive-with-powershell), on the command line [using all kinds of tricks](https://superuser.com/questions/110991/can-you-zip-a-file-from-the-command-prompt-using-only-windows-built-in-capabili).

My favourite and by far the easiest: just install [7zip](http://www.7-zip.org/download.html) using your method of choice, or anyway just make sure it's in your path, and then call this from the commandline:

```
7z a .\obj\Debug\360Survey.zip versionInfo.txt
```

to add versionInfo.txt to the zip file.

Btw if you're using git, you'de use something like this to create the info:

```
git rev-parse --short HEAD > versionInfo.txt
```

or if the repository is somewhere else:

```
git --work-tree=/path/to/x --git-dir=/path/to/x.git rev-parse --short HEAD > versionInfo.txt
```