# Writing a batch utility to archive files on Windows Server 2008 R2

Tags: batch-file, powershell, windows-server-2008, windows-server-2008-r2, archive

I need to write a command line (PowerShell or DOS) utility that will archive all files created in between specified dates present in folder X and store them as a `.zip` package in the same folder.

This utility will be scheduled into windows scheduler where arguments like `to` and `from` dates, `store location` will be provided to it and it will run at specified duration for e.g. at 12:00 noon daily.

Is it possible to write it as a batch `.bat` file? Are there any built-in functionalities inside windows to zip files or I would need to use a third party program like 7-Zip etc for it.

I am not looking for any direction, perhaps a tutorial or something. Both a DOS based and a PowerShell based solution would work for me.

Comment: Maven, do you want files between specified dates, or something like  2014-05-21 to 2014-05-31 including the specified dates?

Comment: Which third party zip program are you using?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would go for PowerShell.

With PowerShell you can easyly build and compare dates with the `Get-Date` commandlet and comparison operators. You could try something like:

```
$folderPath = 'C:\Temp'

$date1 = Get-Date '2014-05-01'
$date2 = Get-Date '2014-05-31'

foreach( $item in (Get-ChildItem $folderPath) )
{
    if( $item.LastWriteTime -ge $date1 -and $item.LastWriteTime -le $date2 )
    {
        # Compression step
    }
}
```

As for compression you have several options like stated in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1153126/how-to-create-a-zip-archive-with-powershell/12978117#12978117).

And for the script parameters you can check [this blog article](http://technet.microsoft.com/fr-fr/magazine/jj554301.aspx).

Comment: If you want it to be portable across regions you can get the local timezone offset with this code `$tzOffset = Get-Date -UFormat '%Z'` and then initialize $date1 and $date2 this way `$date1 = Get-Date "2014-05-01 10:00:00 $tzOffset"`

Comment: Assuming you timezone offset is +02, just do it this way `$date2 = Get-Date '2014-05-31 +02'`, it will use the `00:00:00` time which is the beginning of the day.

Comment: The problem is that it is not between the dates.  It is from 00:00:00 of the first date to 00:00:00 of the start of the last day.  The last day is not included.  It should either be between the dates as asked, or to make them `both` inclusive.

Comment: Then use the `-lt` operator instead `-le`

Comment: That doesn't make it inclusive or exclusive of the two dates, which is the reasonable way to approach this task.

Comment: Don't you see? If you use `-lt` it will include the first day of the range and exclude the last day of the range.   In case you missed it in the flurry of exchanges, the `$date1 and $date2` are already in local time.  No need to use UTC conversion.  The current issue is that `$date2` needs `23:59:59` added to it, to make the range inclusive.  Or add `23:59:59` to `$date1` to make the range exclusive of the two supplied dates.

Comment: I think I see what you mean. If I wanted `$date2` to be inclusive I would use the following test expression `$item.LastWriteTime -lt $date2.AddDays(1)`.

Comment: Yes, and thank you for the syntax - it works well.  One final issue is that it includes folder names.  Can they be excluded?

Comment: You're welcome. You can do this by replacing `Get-ChildItem` with `Get-ChildItem -File` or with PowerShell 2.0 you can replace it with `Get-ChildItem | Where-Object {$_.PSIsContainer -eq $false}`

Comment: Thank you - it works well.  I'll post a batch script wrapped around your work.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a batch file that builds on Cristophe C's powershell script

It takes a `folder` and `two dates` on the command line and writes the last-modified filenames from date1 to date2 into a text file called `daterange.txt`

Some code can be added to zip up the files if further details are added to the question.

```
@echo off
if "%~3"=="" (
echo "%~0" "c:\folder" yyyy-mm-dd1 yyyy-mm-dd2
echo(
echo( This returns last-modified files in the folder from the two dates inclusive
echo( and puts them in a file called "daterange.txt"
echo(
echo( Requires Powershell V3+ (Powershell scripting also needs to be enabled^)
echo(
pause
goto :EOF
) 

set "file=%temp%\psdaterange.ps1"

(
echo( $folderPath = '%~1\'
echo( 
echo( $date1 = Get-Date '%~2'
echo( $date2 = Get-Date '%~3'
echo( 
echo( foreach( $item in (Get-ChildItem -file $folderPath^) ^)
echo( {
echo( if( $item.LastWriteTime -ge $date1 -and $item.LastWriteTime -lt $date2.AddDays(1^) ^)
echo(     {
echo(         Write-Host $folderPath$item
echo(     }
echo( }
) >"%file%"

powershell "%file%" > "daterange.txt"
del "%file%"
```

Answer (score 0):

THere is Compress-Archive utility available in powershell 5.0.

```
# Create a zip file with the contents of C:\Stuff\
Compress-Archive -Path C:\Stuff -DestinationPath archive.zip

# Add more files to the zip file
# (Existing files in the zip file with the same name are replaced)
Compress-Archive -Path C:\OtherStuff\*.txt -Update -DestinationPath archive.zip

# Extract the zip file to C:\Destination\
Expand-Archive -Path archive.zip -DestinationPath C:\Destination
```

See this answer for more details:
[How to create a zip archive with PowerShell?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1153126/how-to-create-a-zip-archive-with-powershell)