# How I can hide the progress bar (compression) in powershell?

Tags: powershell, compression, zip

I am testing a small script to compress files, I compile the script to an executable with "PowerGUI Script Editor", everything works perfect but when you go to run the. exe and compress the file, shows a progress bar, I would like to know how I can hide the progress bar indicating the compression, my code is:

```
$srcdir = mysourcedir
$zipFilename = \zipfilename
$zipFilepath = $env:temp
$zipFile = "$zipFilepath$zipFilename"

#Prepare zip file
if(-not (test-path($zipFile))) {
set-content $zipFile ("PK" + [char]5 + [char]6 + ("$([char]0)" * 18))
(dir $zipFile).IsReadOnly = $false  
} 

$shellApplication = new-object -com shell.application
$zipPackage = $shellApplication.NameSpace($zipFile)
$files = Get-ChildItem -Path $srcdir

foreach($file in $files) { 
$ProgressPreference = ’SilentlyContinue’
$zipPackage.CopyHere($file.FullName)
#using this method, sometimes files can be 'skipped'
#this 'while' loop checks each file is added before moving to the next
while($zipPackage.Items().Item($file.name) -eq $null){
$ProgressPreference = ’SilentlyContinue’
    Start-sleep -seconds 1
}
}
```

the progress bar that I want hide is this:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/LlUVQ.png

I really need help, I hope someone can help me to solve my problem, thanks

Answer (score 3):

The progress bar comes from the [`CopyHere`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb787866%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) method, not from PowerShell, so setting `$ProgressPreference = 'SilentlyContinue'` won't help. Theoretically you could pass a second parameter with value 4 to the function in order to suppress that dialog:

```
$zipPackage.CopyHere($file.FullName, 4)
```

but as documented, that parameter is ignored for zip files:

> **Note** In some cases, such as compressed (.zip) files, some option flags may be ignored by design.

---

If you have PowerShell 3 and .Net framework 4.5 you could use the [`ZipFile`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/system.io.compression.zipfile) class instead of the `Shell.Application` object:

```
Add-Type -Assembly System.IO.Compression.FileSystem
$cl = [IO.Compression.CompressionLevel]::Optimal
[IO.Compression.ZipFile]::CreateFromDirectory($srcdir, $zipFile, $cl, $false)
```

Otherwise try one of the other methods outlined in the answers to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1153126/1630171).

Answer (score 0):

Ansgar is right but there is still a way to hide it.

You can hide it by searching for all the windows (`while` loop) with the title "Compressing..." and hide them.
But this is not enough because if the file is too small, you will not have the window and the `while` loop will run forever.
This problem is because `CopyHere` is asynchronous function.
To get over this this I also added a check to see when the file is not locked and then remove all the jobs.

```
Function Test-FileLock {
      param (
        [parameter(Mandatory=$true)][string]$Path
      )

      $oFile = New-Object System.IO.FileInfo $Path

      if ((Test-Path -Path $Path) -eq $false) {
        return $false
      }

      try {
        $oStream = $oFile.Open([System.IO.FileMode]::Open, [System.IO.FileAccess]::ReadWrite, [System.IO.FileShare]::None)

        if ($oStream) {
          $oStream.Close()
        }
        $false
      } catch {
        # file is locked by a process.
        return $true
      }
}


$scriptBlock = {
    $FORCEMINIMIZE_STATE   = 11
    $HIDE_STATE            = 0
    $MAXIMIZE_STATE        = 3
    $MINIMIZE_STATE        = 6
    $RESTORE_STATE         = 9
    $SHOW_STATE            = 5
    $SHOWDEFAULT_STATE     = 10
    $SHOWMAXIMIZED_STATE   = 3
    $SHOWMINIMIZED_STATE   = 2
    $SHOWMINNOACTIVE_STATE = 7
    $SHOWNA_STATE          = 8
    $SHOWNOACTIVATE_STATE  = 4
    $SHOWNORMAL_STATE      = 1

$member = @"
[DllImport("user32.dll")]
public static extern bool ShowWindowAsync(IntPtr hWnd, int nCmdShow);
"@

    $script:showWindowAsync = Add-Type -memberDefinition $member -name "Win32ShowWindowAsync" -namespace Win32Functions -passThru

    $continue = $true
    do{
        $processes = Get-Process | where {$_.MainWindowTitle -eq "Compressing..." }
        foreach($proc in $processes)
        {
            if(![string]::IsNullOrEmpty($proc))
            {
                $null = $showWindowAsync::ShowWindowAsync($proc.MainWindowHandle, $HIDE_STATE)
                $continue = $false
            }
        }
    }while($continue)
}

$job = Start-Job -ScriptBlock $scriptBlock

#############################################
# Your CopyHere function                    #
 $zipPackage.CopyHere($file.FullName)
###########################################

# Checking when the compression will finish
do{
    Start-Sleep 2
}while((Test-FileLock $zipPackage))

Stop-Job $job
Get-Job | Remove-Job
```