# Remove-Item error when compressing directory in PowerShell

Tags: powershell, zip

I'm attempting to zip up a folder with everything inside except for a single document, then output that compressed folder to a new location. However, when I do so, I get a Remove-Item error

```
Remove-Item : Cannot find path 'C:\Folder\123\12345\12345-A.zip' because it does not exist.
At C:\windows\system32\windowspowershell\v1.0\Modules\Microsoft.PowerShell.Archive\Microsoft.PowerShell.Archive.psm1:233 char:21
+ ...             Remove-Item -LiteralPath $DestinationPath -Force -Recurse ...
+                 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (C:\Folder...12345\12345-A.zip:String) [Remove-Item], ItemNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : PathNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.RemoveItemCommand
```

I don't have Remove-Item anywhere in my code, and the error appears to originate from an internal PowerShell module, only I can't figure out what caused it.

Unfortunately I'm in a position where I can't readily download alternative compressing libraries, as suggested in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32103732/powershell-compress-archive-file-size-issue) thread.

Here is the relevant code:

```
Copy-Item -path $path -destination "$destination\$doc_project_folder\$doc_project_rev\"
Write-Host "Copied to $destination\$doc_project_folder\$doc_project_rev"
Get-ChildItem $document_hash[$doc] | Where { $_.Name -notin $docs_to_exclude} | 
              Compress-Archive -DestinationPath "$destination\$doc_project_folder\$doc_project_rev\$doc_number.zip" -compressionlevel fastest
```

This error is preventing me from successfully outputting the compressed folder to my desired location. What is causing this error, and/or what should I change to solve it?

Answer (score 0):

In my case, using the `Expand-Archive` led to exactly the same `Remove-Item` error. This code was throwing the error:

```
Expand-Archive $zipFileName -DestinationPath $targetFolder
```

After experimenting a bit, it turned out that **adding the `-Force` parameter solves the problem**:

```
Expand-Archive $zipFileName -DestinationPath $targetFolder -Force
```

Manually checking the extracted archive confirmed that it was correctly extracted.

I still do not know what causes the issue, which bugs me a bit. But adding the `-Force` parameter solved the issue in my case. Maybe it will work in your case as well.