# How can I get TeamCity to zip a zip file

Tags: zip, teamcity

My problem: I have build on TeamCity that produces a zip file: Files.zip
It contains lots of files, and a zip file is a good container for the files.

Sadly though, and due to legacy reasons, the zip file has no version number in it's title. I would like it to have a version number in it. 
Like this: Files.1.2.3.4.zip

I thought that maybe I could create a containing zip, that I can adorn with a version number, like this: ContainingZip.1.2.3.4.zip!Files.zip
So that Files.zip is zipped into another zip! (Madness).

But I cannot work out how to do that through TeamCity and it's artifact paths?

What I feel should work is:
/**/*.* => Files.Zip => ContainingZip.1.2.3.4.zip!Files.zip
But that just makes Files.Zip

Breaking it into two steps, works not too:
/**/*.* => Files.Zip
Files.Zip => ContainingZip.1.2.3.4.zip
This doesn't work either as Files.zip doesn't exist when the artifact existence checks are done.

Anyone know how to do this?
(Or do I have to pre-zip in a build step?)

Thanks.

Comment: Where does the version number value come from?

Comment: Who creates `Files.zip`? Your build step, or a `/**/. => Files.Zip` artifact rule?

Comment: Artifact rule. We have "/**/. => Files.Zip" at present. But please note that Files.zip is the name and format we require, just I would like to zip it again, into a versioned zip file.

Comment: you can rewrite a command line (powershell for windows) script to just rename the zip file. Do you really need to zip a zip file. in case you do , a better alternative is to tar it up

Comment: What benefit does taring the file give me? (All our systems are windows FYI).

Comment: You can try with custom command line commands

Answer (score 1):

Answer: TeamCity will not let you double zip in the artifact window. You have to use a build step.

Which you can do...

Via a PowerShell build step you can use Compress-Archive if you have PowerShell 5+.
Or there is good infomation here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1153126/how-to-create-a-zip-archive-with-powershell for older PowerShell versions.

Via an Ant build step:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project name="zipper" default="zip" basedir=".">

<property name="project-name" value="Files.zip" />
<property name="folder-to-zip" value="./FolderToZip/" />

<target name="zip">
<delete file="${project-name}" />
<zip destfile="${project-name}" basedir="${folder-to-zip}" excludes="${project-name}" />
</target>
</project>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use parameter references in the artifacts path, so if you define a configuration parameter called, say, VersionNumber that contains the version number value and use an artifact definition of

```
/**/. => Files.%VersionNumber%.Zip
```

then you will get the desired output.

Comment: Thanks, but that doesn't answer my question. I was asking how do I put an artifact into a zip file. When that artifact is a zip file itself.

Comment: Apologies for misunderstanding. I do not believe TeamCity will allow you to double-zip a file like that using one build configuration and you would have to create a second build configuration that just has an artifact dependency on the first one and then use that to zip it again.

Comment: you should submit that as an answer. 'No you can't' is still an answer.

Comment: old question but I am pretty sure with filename=> blah.zip you can add a file to a zip package

Comment: You can use 7-zip or something to update an existing zip in a command-line build step, then output the result as an artefact. BTW. I upvoted this Q as it solved my problem (to create a zip in TC :))