# Need to export IIS Logs & Tomcat Logs by day in zipped files on Windows 2008 R2

Tags: java, powershell, batch-file, tomcat, iis

I am trying to create a script that zips files according to date(one day of Tomcat logs & one day of IIS Logs), then moves the appropriate zip file to a share.

I have tried to use several powershell scripts and batch files(.cmd) to get this done, all with no avail.

I have also tried to use http://exchangeserverpro.com/powershell-script-iis-logs-cleanup but cannot get it to work on a daily basis.

Can anyone help? I got the following to work but cant seem to figure out how to get the files to be exported before they are deleted

```
$purge = (Get-Date).AddDays(-1)
$path = "D:\Tomcat\apache-tomcat-7.0.39\logs"

# Delete files older than the $purge.
Get-ChildItem -Path $path -Recurse -Force | Where-Object { !$_.PSIsContainer -and $_.CreationTime -lt $purge } | Remove-Item -Force
```

Answer (score 1):

You already have a script to retrieve the log files depending on the `CreatonTime`. Now you need to [Zip the files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1153126/how-to-create-a-zip-archive-with-powershell) and move them using the [Move-Item](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849852(v=wps.620).aspx) cmdlet to the share (you don't need to copy them because you want to delete them anyway).

Answer (score 0):

First, See how to Zip with Powershell:

[How to create a zip archive with PowerShell?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1153126/how-to-create-a-zip-archive-with-powershell)

```
...
$FilesToPurge = Get-ChildItem -Path $path -Recurse -Force | Where-Object { !$_.PSIsContainer -and $_.CreationTime -lt $purge }
```

Add the Files to ZIP:

```
$FilesToPurge | Write-Zip \\Server\Share\Archive.zip # or any other function.
```

Delete the Items:

```
$FilesToPurge | Remove-Item
```