# Using Compress-Archive in Powershell

Tags: powershell

I am attempting to create a zip from from a folder using powershell 5 on Windows 10. After looking at this stackoverflow [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1153126/how-to-create-a-zip-archive-with-powershell) I am trying out the Compress-Archive method.

When I Type in:

```
Compress-Archive -Path 'C:\Users\Test\demo' -DestinationPath 'C:\Users\Test\demo.zip' -verbose
```

I get a verbose error saying:

```
VERBOSE: The partially created archive file 'C:\Users\Test\demo.zip' is deleted as it is not usable.
```

I've looked everywhere online and I'm not able to find a solution to this. Anyone know whats going on?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This message can appear if the folder you are compressing is empty.

Answer (score 0):

I had this same problem,

My path directory was holding a `*`, it was like

`d:\somedirectory\*`, I removed the * and it worked when it looked like `d:\somedirectory`

So my take is that you need to be extra careful when it comes to the path.