# Windows Powershell equivalent of bash command

Tags: excel, git, bash, powershell

I'm trying to use git for Excel files. However, I have to unzip and zip the components together later to accomplish this. For this task I wrote a script which turned out to be easy on MacOS. Since I'm not using Windows myself, I don't know how to fully convert this script into Windows Power Shell commands properly. How can I execute the following bash command in Windows Power Shell?

```
find . -type f | xargs zip ../../MyExcelFile.xlsm
```

What I haven't tried out yet, is unzipping the file. In bash there is the following command:

```
unzip MyExcelFile.xlsm -d XML/MyExcelFileXML
```

Does it do the same in Windows Power Shell or how can I convert that?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: I fail to see what this has to do with git? As for creating a compressed archive, Powershell has a `Compress-Archive` command.

Comment: Not before PowerShell v5, though.

Comment: suggest to also check out [git-bash](https://git-for-windows.github.io/) for windows

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PowerShell doesn't have an exact equivalent to `find`. Normally you'd use `Get-ChildItem` and emulate the filter parameters of the `find` command with a `Where-Object` filter. In your case for instance like this:

```
Get-ChildItem . -Recurse | Where-Object { -not $_.PSIsContainer }
```

In PowerShell v3 or newer you could also do this particular statement with `Get-ChildItem` alone:

```
Get-ChildItem . -Recurse -File
```

Instead of `xargs` you'd normally use a `ForEach-Object` loop (if the downstream command can't read from the pipeline by itself).

There is no builtin `zip` or `unzip` command in Windows, though (at least not prior to PowerShell v5). You can either use the Windows ports of those commands available from [GnuWin32](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/), replace the commands with another external command like [7-zip](http://7-zip.org/), or write functions to utilize the API methods for handling zip archives (see for instance [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1153126/1630171)).