# Compressing a folder into multiple zip archives

Tags: powershell, zip, command-prompt

I know that in a linux enviroment it is possible to zip a folde into multiple smaller zip archives as such:

`zip -r -s 64 archive.zip FolderName/`

But is there an equivalent option using powershell or commandprompt?

Comment: duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1153126/how-to-create-a-zip-archive-with-powershell?rq=1

Comment: @pandemic it is *not* a duplicate.  Here the OP asks how to do a zip archive split on based on size.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to create a multi-part zip archive you can give [DotNetZip](https://archive.codeplex.com/?p=dotnetzip) a shot.

This is how it works in C#

```
using (ZipFile zip = new ZipFile())
{
  zip.UseUnicode= true;
  zip.AddDirectory(@"Folder");
  zip.MaxOutputSegmentSize = 100*1024 ; // 100k segments
  zip.Save("MyFiles.zip");
}
```

Or if you can settle with 7zip, there is [7ZipPowershell](https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/7Zip4Powershell) that allows you to do just that:

```
PS> Install-Module -Name 7Zip4Powershell
PS> Compress-7Zip -Path . -VolumeSize 102400 -ArchiveFileName "C:\Users\me\Desktop\abc.7z"
```

PS: The segment size is in both cases in byte.