# How do I compress a file in PowerShell v2.0

Tags: powershell-2.0

I am using PowerShell 2.0 and can not update to a later version. I need to be able to compress a folder into a ZIP. I have scoured Stack Overflow and have found nothing that helps me.

This is one thing that I have tried and it throws an error.

```bsh
Add-Type -Assembly "System.IO.Compression.FileSystem"
[io.compression.zipfile]::CreateFromDirectory("Source", "Destination")
```

I wanted this to compress the folder that I specified at "Source" and put it in the specified "Destination"

I got this error:
Add-Type : Cannot add type. The assembly 'System.IO.Compression.FileSystem' could not be found.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Welcome to SO!

First, this is a possible duplicate of [How to create a zip archive with PowerShell?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1153126/how-to-create-a-zip-archive-with-powershell) - however, I believe I have an answer that is slightly better so I'll post it.

I suspect that the assembly not loading is a question of .NET framework installed rather than Powershell version, FWIW. You might like to see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2094694/how-can-i-run-powershell-with-the-net-4-runtime/5069146#5069146).

The answer with the least amount of faffing is probably Jeff Hicks' post [here](https://www.petri.com/create-zip-archives-with-powershell-and-the-shell-application-com-object). In case the link goes dark, I've abridged it to the bare bones:

```
Set-Content $OutputPath ("PK" + [char]5 + [char]6 + ("$([char]0)" * 18))
$ZipFile = Get-Item $OutputPath
$ZipFile.IsReadOnly = $false  

$shell = New-Object -com shell.application
$zipPackage = $shell.NameSpace($zipfile.fullname)
$zipPackage.CopyHere($Path)
```

For completeness, here's the equivalent unzipper:

```
$shell = new-object -com shell.application
$zip   = $shell.NameSpace($Path)
foreach($item in $zip.items())
{
    $shell.Namespace($Destination).CopyHere($item) | out-null
}
```

Excuse the wonky capitalisation - it makes my eyes hurt - but I'm sure you'll pretty it up as you please.

If this is a good answer, please mark it as such; otherwise, tell me what broke and I'll try to improve it.